# Samba, NTFS drive and win7

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, samba

I've just added to my unix server ( just shoved it in) an ntfs drive with some stuff and I want to access it through win7 (home edition). After a small struggle I've managed to get  access to the server files from win7 but not to the mentioned ntfs drive . It works  but I can't log with any of the samba users. When I try to change form %S to a specific user or force one it just doesn't connect. Any ideas?

```
 [NTFS drive]
comment = Samba server's NTFS disk
path = /media/sdc1
valid users = %S
read only = No
create mask = 0775
directory mask = 0775
guest ok = No
```

Comment: What doesn't connect where? Your question makes no sense. You've put an NTFS drive into a Unix server and want to access the drive's contents from a Win7 machine? Either way, this is offtopic and should be on serverfault.

Comment: pretty much, yes...

Comment: what are the last lines from samba's logs when you can't log on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have mounted the drive via ntfs-3g this is probably just a permissions issue. Samba impersonates the user you are connecting with to a share when accessing underlying filesystem resources, unless you use the ["force user"](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#FORCEUSER) directive with your share definition.

Take a look at the permissions of /media/sdc1 and check what users do have file ownership and what the access masks do look like. You can create a [user mapping](http://b.andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/permissions.html) from NTFS security descriptor's SIDs to your unix users.

If you just need a quick & dirty solution, you could create a new user "ntfsadmin", use `force user = ntfsadmin` in your smb.conf and set the `uid` [option to mount](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/) to ntfsadmin's UID - this would enable all users to read and change everything on your NTFS volume regardless of any ACLs set.